# How to return GZIP responses with Spring Webflux?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

Let's say I have a very simple HTTP endpoint using Spring Webflux:

```
@GetMapping
fun greeting(@RequestParam("msg") val message : String) = Mono.just(Greeting(message))
```

where `Greeting` is a simple DTO serialized as JSON. How can I instruct Spring Webflux to return the response compressed as GZIP? I'm using the Netty implementation if that matters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are looking for is server compression properties

```
server.compression.enabled=true
server.compression.min-response-size=1024
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, are you sure it should work for webflux?

Comment: It seem to work if I also add: `server.compression.mime-types: application/json, application/hal+json`

Comment: When I request with accept-encoding:*, the response is coming with content-encoding: zstd. Any reason for that. I was expecting gzip

Answer (score 2):

Adding to above-accepted answer, it's always better to give min-response-size as well to remove server overhead of compressing all responses and also the the mime-types.

```
server.compression.enabled=true
server.compression.mime-types=text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript,application/json,application/xml
server.compression.min-response-size=2KB
```