Spring WebFlux - configure client to not decompress data
I'm writing a spring project and I want to use reactive programming.
I started with creating a client bean:
@Bean
public WebClient webClient() {
    return WebClient
            .builder()
            .build();
}

And after that I created a code that sends a request to dynamic URIs:
public Mono<Response> reactiveSendRequest(String body, URI url, String method, HttpHeaders headers) {
    return webClient
            .method(HttpMethod.valueOf(method.toUpperCase()))
            .uri(url)
            .bodyValue(body)
            .headers(h -> h.addAll(headers))
            .retrieve()
            .toEntity(byte[].class)
            .timeout(this.timeout)
            .map(rawResponse -> {
                return new Response(rawResponse);
            });


I'm doing a wrapping to the response entity into a Response object, we can ignore this part.
My app should behave as a proxy, which means, that I want to get the data from the endpoint that I'm sending a request to in the same way.
I'm sending a response to an endpoint that returns the data gzip-ed, with accept encoding header with gzip value and it looks like the client is decompressing the data, and also removing the content-encoding header from the response.
I wan't to avoid it - I want to get the compressed data as is without any manipulations, just receiving the entity with the raw bytes.
Currently I'm doing block at the end just to test and make sure that the client behaves as I expect.
Anyone has any ideas on how to handle this problem?
Thanks in advance!
I tried to find some congihrations for the client that can say something about decompression but I didn't find anything related.

Any specific reason you do not use Spring API Gateway ? It is designed to create proxies for web-services, with capabilities like path rewrite, security, etc.

@amanin i actually want to be the one that takes the https call, the uri is dynamic and changed on each request, but i will try to read about it more and maybe it will be a better choice for me. I need to do some analyzations before and after on the request and response and make some changes in headers and so on

Does this stack overflow here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55237276/how-to-return-gzip-responses-with-spring-webflux help to solve the issue? Question is in Kotlin but I believe the properties should be the same. I would also see what default codec is being loaded to handle this and what it is doing.

Also not sure if you want the timeout or if you need more of a sync call you can add .block() like here https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webflux-webclient/client-synchronous.html

I ran into a similar scenario where I wanted to write a unit test for the various compression scenarios, however, the WebTestClient always returns the decompressed response. Here's my workaround to access the raw response as well as the original headers.

Disable compression on the WebClient. This will disable both response decompression as well as the "Accept-Encoding=gzip" request header.
@Bean
public WebClient webClient() {
  return WebClient
    .builder()
    .clientConnector(
      new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create().compress(false)))
      // ^ disabling compression
    .build();
}


Manually add the "Accept-Encoding=gzip" request header. This will ensure that the server responds with the compressed payload, but the client doesn't decompress it.
public Mono<Response> reactiveSendRequest(
  String body, URI url, String method, HttpHeaders headers) {
  return webClient
    .method(HttpMethod.valueOf(method.toUpperCase()))
    .uri(url)
    .bodyValue(body)
    .headers(h -> h.addAll(headers))
    .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
    // ^ manually adding the header back
    .retrieve()
    .toEntity(byte[].class)
    .timeout(this.timeout)
    .map(rawResponse -> {
      return new Response(rawResponse);
    });
}



